# IDictionary<string, object> to an npgsqlParmeterCollection?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I currently have an Idictionary<string,object> containing parameter which needs to be parsed to an npgsqlcommand.

The dictionary contains the parameter and their value but is there an easy way to convert from the idictionary to an collection of npgsqlcollection with IDictionary parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to infer the database type from your objects:

```
var parameters = dictionary.Select(kvp => new NpgsqlParameter(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToArray();
command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Comment: What in the case of IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>  where the key is the same?for multipole statements?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Each dictionary should create a separate collection of parameters?

Comment: So in my case this would be like this 
``var parameters = entry.Select(x=>x.dictionary.Select(kvp => new NpgsqlParameter(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToArray());
command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);``
The set of keys for every entry is the same, but the values are the same. 

So i assume your approach will not work for this or?

Comment: You would need to iterate over `entry` and create a new `NpgsqlCommand` at each iteration. Something like `foreach (var dictionary in entry) { /* create command */ command.Parameters.AddRange(dictionary.Select(kvp => new NpgsqlParameter(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToArray()); }`

Comment: Yeah, but I then seem to run into casting issues => i guess there is no way around it then... then to manually out them into a list, and cast the entire list

Comment: @kafka I'm not following; it would be helpful if you could share your code, preferably in a new question as your requirements have changed.